# Don't send correct file to clientbrowser

Tags: php, excel, server, client, phpexcel

I wrote a function which generates an .xlsx file out of SQL Data. (This works totally fine) but when I want to sent the file to the Clientbrowser it just sends me an .xlsx with php-errors and php-echos in there.
Although it sends an .xlsx file to the server where the correct output will be generated.

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"HPALM_Auslieferung-". $kunde. "_". $datum. ".xlsx\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
$Writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$Writer->save("HPALM_Auslieferung-". $kunde. "_". $datum. ".xlsx");
```

I also tried to change it to

```
$Writer->save("php://output");
```

but then it only sends the .xlsx file with the php-errors/echos to the client and no .xlsx file to the server.

Comment: If you're sending a file to the browser ("php://output") then that must be the ___only___ thing sent to the browser.... if you echo anything, then of course that will also be sent to the browser, and will corrupt the file that you're trying to send.... of course the fact that you're seeing errors is also being echoed to the browser, and corrupting the file..... .but have you considered that those error messages might actually be telling you what you're doing wrong?

Comment: And if you save to a filename like `"HPALM_Auslieferung-". $kunde. "_". $datum. ".xlsx"`, then yes, that will be a file saved on the server..... to send to the browser, always use `"php://output"` (as the documentation and examples all tell you to do)

Comment: I removed the echo and turned off the Errorhandling.
Now I get an empty file...

Comment: Is it empty only when you send it to the browser (`php://output`), but has the data when you save it to `HPALM_Auslieferung-". $kunde. "_". $datum. ".xlsx`?

Comment: Check whether it's really empty by opening it in a text editor, not in MS Excel

Comment: The Errormessage just telling me to use mysqli instead of mysql for the mysql_connect. But that should not affect PHPExcel or does it?

Comment: As I told when I send it to the server everything is fine.
Yes its really empty. I needed to open it with a texteditor to even figure out that there are php-outputs in.

Comment: Of course it affects PHPExcel..... an error message is output that's being sent to a browser, and ___any___ output sent to the browser will corrupt the file

Comment: The dirty workround is to ob_flush immediately before the `save()`.... the real solution is to fix the errors (e.g to switch to using MySQLi instead of MySQL)

Comment: So even with turned off errorhandling it affects the file?
Well than I have to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: My bad, ob_clean() rather than ob_flush() before the save()